# SVG text, tspan font-size and centered

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an issue with font size on SVG as us can see in svg the font-size:16px different from paragraph font-size but the they have the same value `16px`. I would like to have font size in svg such on paragraph.

The second issue, it's how to center  `<tspan text-anchor="middle" class="tc-label-value">85</tspan>` when I delete       `<tspan class="label-text" text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="50" dy="15">Text in SVG</tspan>`
I mean the is a case when I have `Text in svg` and have not 
https://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/BaaKbze

Comment: Your actual SVG size is 180X180px. Since the SVG's viewbox is 100x100, the SVG content is scaled by ratio 1.8. Either set the width and height absolute values explicitly, or remove the viewBox attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG text, & span font-size and center solution

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wr {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.label-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tc-label-value {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.par {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wr'>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="100%" style="display: block;">
            <path d="M 95.5 50 A 45.5 45.5 0 1 1 11.315120324302569 26.047336589080288" stroke-width="9" stroke-dasharray="168.16760675098308" stroke-dashoffset="2.842170943040401e-14" stroke="#a3bfff" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" style="transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-out 0s;"></path>
            <path d="M 11.315120324302569 26.047336589080288 A 45.5 45.5 0 0 1 95.5 49.999999999999986" stroke-width="9" stroke-dasharray="117.71732472568812" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#66bb6a" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" style="transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-out 0s;"></path>
            <text transform="translate(50)" x="0" y="50">
                <tspan text-anchor="middle" class="tc-label-value">85</tspan>
                <tspan class="label-text" text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="50" dy="15">Text in SVG</tspan>
            </text>
        </svg>
  <p class='par'>Text Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The font size for the svg element should be 8.88px. Why? Because the svg's width is 100 units or px ( viewBox="0 0 **100** 100" ) and is scaled up to 180px ( `.wr{width: 180px;}` ). Since you need the font size inside the svg to look like 16px, the real font size should be 16 * 100 / 180 = 8.88

```css
.wr {
  width: 180px; 
}
.par{
  font-size: 16px;
}

svg{font-size: 8.88px;}
```

```html
<div class='wr'>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display: block;">
    <path d="M 95.5 50 A 45.5 45.5 0 1 1 11.315120324302569 26.047336589080288" stroke-width="9" stroke-dasharray="168.16760675098308" stroke-dashoffset="2.842170943040401e-14" stroke="#a3bfff" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" style="transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-out 0s;"></path>
      <path d="M 11.315120324302569 26.047336589080288 A 45.5 45.5 0 0 1 95.5 49.999999999999986" stroke-width="9" stroke-dasharray="117.71732472568812" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke="#66bb6a" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" style="transition: stroke-dashoffset 500ms ease-out 0s;"></path>
    <text transform="translate(50)" x="0" y="50">
      <tspan text-anchor="middle" class="tc-label-value">85</tspan>
      <tspan class="label-text" text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="50" dy="15">Text in SVG</tspan>       
    </text>
 </svg>
  <p class='par'>Text Paragraph</p>
</div>
```